# How do I handle this response from YQL

Tags: javascript, unicode, ascii, yql

In a request to YQL `(select * from html where url="...")` I got the following response:

```
callback({
    "query":
        {"count":"1","created":"2011-05-09T23:29:05Z","lang":"en-US"
     }, "results": ["<body>... we\ufffdll call Mr ...</body>"]
}
```

This is from the YQL console page.
When I type that sequence into firebug (even on YQL's page) I get:

```
... we�ll call Mr ...
```

What am I doing wrong? Is YQL's site in a bad encoding? Is there some way to convert symbols like this to their ascii equivalent?

BTW this isn't my site so it's not like I can change the meta charset on that site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It seems like that (the question mark in a solid black diamond) is what you *should* be seeing: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/browsertest.htm
- The comment on that [character's page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) says:

  > used to replace an incoming character whose value is unknown or unrepresentable in Unicode

Maybe the answers to these might help get a better answer:

1. What character are you expecting at that place?
2. Can you post the URL that you're scraping?
3. Is that the character on that page also or is it getting mangled when picked up by YQL?

**Update**

You might want to check out the `charset` option in the `where` clause of your YQL query - I'm not entirely sure what it does but it looks like it forces the YQL engine to use the specified charset when parsing the page. Perhaps setting it to `UTF-8` will solve your problem.

For example,

```
select * from html where url = 'http://google.com' and charset='utf-8'
```

Comment: It's getting mangled already by YQL, I'm expecting either a single quote or double quote. The main site has the quotes all curly like in MS Word

Comment: @qwertymk Would it be possible to post a URL that reproduces this behaviour? I've tried a few pages that use the smart/curly quotes but it seems to work fine for me so it's probably something that's specific to the page you're fetching data from.

Comment: I don't currently have it on me, it's on my other computer

Comment: @qwertymk It might help if you post that when you are able to get to it. In the meantime, I've posted an update to my answer that might be a fix for the issue - the `html` table supports a `charset` option - you might try setting it to `UTF-8` and see if you get a usable response now. I was able to see tons of `\ufffd`s in the response when I forced the charset to `ASCII`.

Comment: @no.good.at.coding: Can you give me an example of how to do this? I'm completely lost when it comes to YQL

Comment: I've posted an example, does that help?

Comment: I'll give it a shot, how do I find out a site's charset though? (they don't have any `<meta>` tags for it)

Comment: I think the problem might be a wrong charset - it can be specified in a few different ways so a meta tag isn't required. I would try forcing `UTF-8` first and seeing if that works and also posting the URL so that others can use YQL and see the results first hand. At this point however, I'm not too sure about how you might try to figure out the correct encoding used on the page.

Comment: I don't know why but YQL isn't giving me that error. I didn't change anything though. Anyway thanks for the help

Comment: @qwertymk I'm no expert on character encoding so I'm getting a little out of my depth here but here's what seemed to work for me on my Win 7 machine using FF4.0.1 - I see that the browser is interpreting the page encoding as `ISO-8859-1` (right click > View Page Info > General). When I force YQL to use that encoding `select * from html where url = '<url>' and charset = 'ISO-8859-1'`, instead of `\ufffd`, I get `\u0092`, `\u0093` and `\u0094`.

Comment: On my machine, these render as various [single (')](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/92/index.htm) and [double (")](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/93/index.htm) [quotes (")](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/94/index.htm). I also found [these](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html) [pages](http://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/ISO8859/8859-1.TXT) to be useful - they show the mapping between the ISO-8859 (the ISO Latin-1 if I understand correctly) and UTF-8.

Comment: In UTF-8, 0x92, 0x93 and 0x94 are control characters that don't really have a visual representation (perhaps the 'square-outline') while in ISO Latin-1 they represent the curly quotes you see in Word. I'm not really sure how you might deal with these - a simple but brittle way might be to search and replace - but I don't know enough to say if it is even a feasible hack since it only considers 3 characters and is based on what I've seen so far. I might be making incorrect assumptions and you might run into more cases and handling each individually, yourself, isn't how you want to proceed.